# How to loop a click on a button and then go one down

Tags: python, selenium, twitter, automation

I am currently trying to code a bot on Python which should follow followers of a user on Twitter. I am pretty new to Python that is why am asking this question.

**What I want:**

1. Get the follow button.
2. Click on the follow button.
3. Delay.
4. Go to the next button
5. Repeat x times. (Should not be infinite but so that you can change the amount.)

My current code:

````
import time
import sys
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep
import pickle
import pprint


class TwitterBot:
    def __init__ (self, username, password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.bot = webdriver.Chrome()


    def login (self):
        bot = self.bot
        bot.get("https://twitter.com/login")
        time.sleep(3)
        email = bot.find_element_by_class_name("r-30o5oe.r-1niwhzg.r-17gur6a.r-1yadl64.r-deolkf.r-homxoj.r-poiln3.r-7cikom.r-1ny4l3l.r-t60dpp.r-1dz5y72.r-fdjqy7.r-13qz1uu")
        password = bot.find_element_by_name("session[password]")
        email.send_keys(self.username)
        password.send_keys(self.password)
        password.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        time.sleep(3)


    def follow (self, user):
        bot = self.bot
        bot.get("https://twitter.com/"+ user + "/followers/")
        time.sleep(3)
        users= bot.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@data-testid='UserCell']//span[contains(text(),'Follow')]")
        users.click()




BOT = TwitterBot("MYUSERNAME", "MYPASSWORD")
BOT.login()
BOT.follow("A_USER")```
````

Answer (score 0):

```
    def follow (self, user):
        while True:
            bot = self.bot
            bot.get("https://twitter.com/"+ user + "/followers/")
            time.sleep(2)
            wait = time.sleep(1)
            follow = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//span[text()="Follow"]')))
            follow.click()
```

Comment: Thanks! But this is just a loop which always clicks on the first button. I would like to click on the next one after clicking one.

Comment: so if i understand you correctly you want it that it follows every account of an chosen twitter account lets say a bot that follows every follower that cristiano ronaldo follows. or do you want a bot that just follows someone randomly then another one randomly ?

Comment: Just go trough the list it doesn't have to be randomized. Just start at Person A and end at Person Z.

Answer (score 0):

So, starting from what you already have done, as the `follow()` function, already gets the `follow button` and **click** it, for implementing in your program also `4.` and `5.` objectives, you can do as follows:

1. For getting all the `follow buttons`, you can do an **`array`** from all
   the `elements` of the `twitter follow buttons class` that's the following:

`class="css-18t94o4 css-1dbjc4n r-1niwhzg r-p1n3y5 r-sdzlij r-1phboty r-rs99b7 r-1w2pmg r-15ysp7h r-gafmid r-1ny4l3l r-1fneopy r-o7ynqc r-6416eg r-lrvibr`

and store it in a variable, so:

```
followButtons = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[class="css-18t94o4 css-1dbjc4n r-1niwhzg r-p1n3y5 r-sdzlij r-1phboty r-rs99b7 r-1w2pmg r-15ysp7h r-gafmid r-1ny4l3l r-1fneopy r-o7ynqc r-6416eg r-lrvibr"]'), element => element);
```

2. Once you have all the `follow clickable elements`, you can click them with the `click()` function, with a `for loop` and also set the `delay` (3.) with `time.sleep`:

```
for (i = 0; i < followButtons.length; i++) {
  followButtons[i].click()
  time.sleep(3)
}
```

I also raccomend you to **await** until the page is **fully loaded** to execute your script, using [async-await function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) and storing the twitter page you open with the browser from your bot, in a variable like `page`:

```
(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();    //using puppeteer as example
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(twitterurl);                 //in twitterurl store the link of the page

    const result = await page.evaluate(() => Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[class="css-18t94o4 css-1dbjc4n r-1niwhzg r-p1n3y5 r-sdzlij r-1phboty r-rs99b7 r-1w2pmg r-15ysp7h r-gafmid r-1ny4l3l r-1fneopy r-o7ynqc r-6416eg r-lrvibr]'), element => element));

//rest of the code

})
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried to rewrite it into Python as you are using Java (At least that's what I was thinking) and did not get it working.